# Capture Image through Camera in the Website and Store the Path of Image in PGAdmin using Django

Tags: javascript, django, postgresql, image, pgadmin

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Capture Image From Camera</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
   </head>
<body>
    <video id="video" width="100" height="100" autoplay></video>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
<script>
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Get access to the camera!
if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true
    }).then(function(stream) {
        //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();
    });
}
 
// Elements for taking the snapshot
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Trigger photo take
document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 100, 100);
});

</script>
</html>
```

'''I have used this code to add a button which will open camera to take a snap.I have to store the path of the image in Pg-admin using Django.I am not able to do this.Please Help Me...'''

Answer (score 0):

You should take the photo using a form than save the results to a database model, in the database model their should be a variable file type and in that you specify where the picture can be saved to. This is with django. I cannot help you with your javascript.